# Cannot find by date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to get my app to pull all posts created on a specific date.

```
case meta_type
    when "user"
        @meta = User.find(params[:user_id])
        @meta_title = @meta.username + "'s Posts"
        @posts = Post.find(:all, :conditions => { :user_id => @meta.id})
    when "category"
        @meta = params[:category]
        @meta_title = @meta + " Posts"
        @posts = Post.find(:all, :conditions => { :category => @meta})
    when "date"
        @meta = Date.parse(params[:date])
        @meta_title = @meta.strftime("%d/%m/%Y") + " Posts"
        @posts = Post.find(:all, :conditions => { :created_at => @meta})
    end
```

Here is my view:

```
  - if @meta
        %h2= @meta_title
        - if @posts.count > 0   
            - @posts.each_slice(2) do |slice|
                .row
                    - slice.each do |post|                  
                        .col-sm-6
                            .blog_entry
                                .img
                                %h3 
                                    %a= link_to post.title, posts_path + '/' + post.id.to_s
                                = render "blog_meta", :post => post
        - else
            %p= @user.username + " has no posts."
    - else
        %h2= "User does not exist."
```

I am getting `undefined method 'username' for nil:NilClass` which in itself isn't a problem, but the fact that it is getting filtered through to the else statement is, because it should be finding posts for that date.

Also I just realised by passing through the datetime, it will actually be looking for posts created at the exact same time, whereas I would like it to pull up all posts created on the day, not the time.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, ignoring the subtleties of exactly which time zone you're evaluating the date in, you can change your when "date" block to read as follows

```
@meta = Date.parse(params[:date])
@meta_title = @meta.strftime("%d/%m/%Y") + " Posts"
beginning_of_day = @meta.to_datetime.beginning_of_day
end_of_day = @meta.to_datetime.end_of_day
@posts = Post.where("created_at >= ?", beginning_of_day).where("created_at < ?", end_of_day).order(:created_at).all
```

That will give you a list of Posts created on the day in question, in the time zone in which your app is running, ordered by creation time.

You can make a number of other adjustments (changing sort order, using a different time zone, etc.) as needed.

Comment: That worked a charm thanks! Now time for me to work out how this piece of code works